Find the minumum value of an expression
I am trying to find the minimum value of this expression satisfying the below condition, but this is not leading into a solution:
NMinimize[a*b^(a*b) - ((a^b) * b) && (a*b^(a*b) - ((a^b) * b)) > 1000, {a, b}]

So I want to find the smallest value of ab^(ab) - ((a^b) * b) which is larger than 1,000
Any idea how to correct this....
Thanks!

NMinimize[{a*b^(a*b) - ((a^b)*b), {a, b} > 0}, {a, b}]

Your question is unclearly formulated: a*b^(a*b) - ((a^b)*b) takes any value greater than 1000. For example, FindInstance[   a*b^(a*b) - ((a^b)*b) == Rationalize[1000.000000001, 0] && a > 0 &&     b > 0, {a, b}, Reals] // N produces {{a -> 1.85094, b -> 3.05421}}.

This is a question of the type: Which minimal number is greater than 1.

There is a continuum of solutions for which (a*b^(a*b) - ((a^b)*b)) == 1000, as can be seen from ContourPlot[(a*b^(a*b) - ((a^b)*b)) == 1000, {a, 0, 4}, {b, 0, 4}].

If $a=1$, the function you are trying to minimize looks like this:

and it can get infinitely close to the value of 1000. Therefore, the question only makes sense if $a$ and $b$ are integers; and with proper constraints and NMinimize syntax the answer is instant:
ClearAll[a, b]
NMinimize[{
  a*b^(a*b) - ((a^b)*b),
  (a*b^(a*b) - ((a^b)*b)) > 1000 && a > 0 && b > 0
  },
 {a, b} \[Element] Integers]

{1434., {a -> 2, b -> 3}}


+1. Assuming a and b  integer, the bases  of the powers may be also less than or equal to zero.

Unfortunately, NMinimize[{a*b^(a*b) - ((a^b)*b), (a*b^(a*b) - ((a^b)*b)) > 1000}, {a,     b} \[Element] Integers] is running without any response on my comp for a half an hour.

In this case an optimal solution is a==1001,b==0.

Thanks all! @Victor K. I cannot get that expression to evaluate at all!
